# Strict inequality becoming non-strict in the limit

Tags: limits, inequality

Imagine that you try to prove that $ \displaystyle\lim_{x \to  \infty } \frac{\sin x}{x}$ converges to 0 by squeeze theorem.
So you start bounding $\sin x$ with $-1$ and $1$ so that $-1 ≤ \sin x ≤1$. And then you proceed normaly dividing by $x$ and so on. 
But, if instead of bounding it with $1$ you bound it with $-2$ and $2$, then the inequality would be $-2 < \sin x < 2$ which is strict. So if you proceed as before dividing by $x$ and doing the limit you would get $0<0$ right? Which as i view it is a contradiction, so when does the second inequality become non-strict? And if it is in the process of taking the limit, does all inequalities become non-strict in the  limit?

Comment: Not sure what point you are trying to make.  if $x>0$ then $\frac 1x>0$, strictly,  but in the limit we have $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac 1x=0$.  Do you see a contradiction in that?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a contradiction, it is a well known fact that *strict inequalities does not necessarly hold in the limit*, just consider for example

$$a_n = \frac 1n >0$$

with

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1n = 0$$

---

The key point is that in the definition of limit it is not necessarly requested that $\exists n_0$ such that $a_n=L$ for $n\ge n_0$ but just that $|a_n -L|\le \varepsilon$, that is it suffices that $a_n$ approaches $L$ as much as requested $\forall \varepsilon >0$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a contradiction. The theorem states nothing about strict equalities, so you can't imply $0 < 0 < 0$ from $-2 < \sin(x) < 2$. However, they are still usable as you can still imply $-2 \leq \sin(x) \leq 2$, which means $0 \leq \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \leq 0$ by the Squeeze Theorem.

So yes, inequalities become non-strict when taking the limit.